# Android app start only activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am trying to create an app which basically should behave like a shortcut to "Mobile Networks" settings option whenever I open it. I have been able to work it out with below code. Its working correctly but when I click the back button it moves to a screen with white background. Is it possible to just start the activity and not open any other screens?

```
package com.exampl.mobilenetwork;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just call finish(); after startActivity(...)

Comment: Why have MainActivity at all ? Just make NetworkSetting the default Activity.

Comment: When you press back from the Mobile Networks dialog, the system sends you back to your app. From what I am seeing here, your app renders a white screen, hence this is what you observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call finish() after  startActivity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

This works.

Answer (score -1):

One approach would probably be to use android:noHistory=true in your application's manifest.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html